# Can't control Firefox media through the sound indicator or keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sound, firefox, indicator-sound, multimedia

When playing media in Firefox, for example on Youtube.com it would be great if we could control this using our build in audio indicator or the audio keyboard shortcuts. But it looks like Firefox isn't detected as a audio playing source.

Other applications like Spotify or Auryo are detected and controllable. Chromium is detected and controllable, although the artwork (icon) isn't updated.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox doesn't seem to be a MPRIS "provider"
Spec:
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mpris-spec/

Relevant Firefox bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1353652
Seems people are currently implementing this.

Some extra info: websites can share this info using the new Media Session API. Some resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/media-session
- Support: https://caniuse.com/#search=Media%20Session%20API
- Online demo: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media-session/

Answer (score 0):

I do not have problem controlling the sound volume when a youtube video plays in firefox?

The keyboard volume controls work, also the volume slider. I do not know if it is the reason, but I'm using **PulseAudio Volume Control** and using it I can even control firefox audio volume individually than the other applications

[image: PulseAudio Volume Control]

But it is true - using any web browser different that Firefox (tested with Brave, Chromium and Opera) I can see media controls clicking the audio volume icon in wingpannel, but not for **Firefox**, also **Epiphany** is missing.

Comment: I'm hoping that with the MPRIS addition they will also add support for audio buttons like the play/pause button.