# Spotify does not quit properly and Album Art for Spotify Songs in Media Control missing

Tags: release-hera, spotify, multimedia

**Problem 1:**

When closing Spotify, the music stops, but the windows doesn't quit. Clicking repeatedly gives me a "Force Quit" option, as Spotify has stopped responding.

**Problem 2:**

When listening to music via Spotify, (installed via snapstore; Premium Account) I can see and control the current song via the media control on the wingpanel.

However, I'm missing any kind of album art. I only ever get the default "music" icon.

[image: Music Control]

I've seen in [this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21626/no-artwork-shown-for-media-played-through-chromium) that the OP could see their album art from Spotify,
so I assume it must be something about my configuration.

**Info**:

Spotify is installed via the snap store, I have a Premium Account, I'm on Elementary OS 5.1.6 Hera.

I can't recall ever not having the aforementioned problems, but just to be sure, all I remember to have changed regarding Spotify:

- I disabled the notification that occurs after every song in Spotify's settings

**Update**: With a little patience, it seems, Spotify does close normally, although very slowly in my opinion. However, **Problem 2** persists

**Update 2**: While Spotify's still usable, I've taken the problem as a motivation to install mopidy with a spotify backend and iris frontend instead, which was admittedly a totally overblown solution.
I'd still prefer Spotify to work completely, as I'm stubborn like that, but oh well.

Comment: Have you tried the old way of installing Spotify. It could be a snap thing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to elementary, what's "the old way"? I tried to install from flathub, which did not help.

Comment: Okay, I've also tried adding the spotify repository and installing with apt. That version behaves slightly differently (it closes faster, it shows a green spotify icon in the media control, but it still doesn't show album art and it opens a new spotify application everytime I click it in media control it, instead of focusing the existing one.)

Answer (score 0):

Remove Spotify installed from flathub.

Link: https://neverware.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001125187-How-do-you-uninstall-Flatpacks-

Remove Spotify installed old way via terminal.

```
sudo apt purge spotify
```

Install Spotify via terminal:

```
sudo apt install spotify
```

Comment: I assume the prerequisite for this is adding Spotify's repos as described here https://www.spotify.com/de/download/linux/  and then installing spotify-client? Or should I actually be able to install "spotify" and something's messed up?

Comment: Type in Google How to install Spotify in Elementary OS. First link: https://linuxhint.com/install_spotify_elementary_os/ From now always search on your own.

Comment: I was just making sure you didn't mean something I missed, I tried that already, as indicated in the comments on my original post. I might be a newbie to linux, but I would never choose to post a question if I hadn't exhausted what I could easily find on google first, as the barrier of entry is much bigger. 
Thanks anyway, I might just stick with my mopidy installation for now.

Comment: Why you did not open terminal and type spotify? Terminal always shows errors on the screen.